# Property of the two independent solutions of the second order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following is a question posed by a friend.

Let $y_1,y_2$ be the two independent solutions of the differential equation $$y''+Py'+Qy=0.$$ Suppose that $y_1(a)=y_1(b) = 0$ and that $y_1(x)\neq 0 ~\forall x\in (a,b).$ Prove that $y_2(c)=0$ for some $c\in (a,b).$

All I could have was that $y_1'(c)=0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$ by the Rolle's theorem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What function did you apply Rolle's theorem to? Because I can see $y_1(a) = 0 $ and $y_2(b) = 0$.

Comment: @thanasissdr I apply the Rolle's theorem to $y_1$ only!

Comment: In order to apply Rolle's theorem to $y_1$ you need to know 2 values $x_1, x_2$ such that $y_1(x_1) = y_1(x_2)$. How can you know that there are such values?

Comment: @thanasissdr Extremely sorry. It's actually $y_1(a)=y_1(b) = 0$. Edited in the question.